# Is there a gesture to navigate back to previous page in iPad 2 (or the new iPad)?

Tags: multi-touch, ipad

I've just bought a new iPad, but it's so annoying when I have to click the arrow on the top left of the page to navigate back and forth using Safari. I wonder is there a gesture for navigating that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2):

Safari on a standard iPad does not have a gesture for returning to the previous page.

Comment: Sadly and strangely the three-finger swipe doesn't work for back or forward. Not sure why they wouldn't have enabled it.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder is there a way to work around this problem?